# Scrapy - close method body is not executed

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Can't figure out why my close method is not being executed. I have to process two lists of urls. One list have to be processed first and exported and the second list should be processed then.

The problem is that close method is just called (breakpoint stops at the `def` ) but not executed. Do you know why?

```
# coding=utf-8
from bot.items import TestItem
from scrapy import Spider, Request, signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class IndexSpider(Spider):
    name = 'index_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.doman.org']

    def start_requests(self):

        for url in ["https://www.doman.org/eshop"]:

            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_main_page)

    def parse_main_page(self, response):
        self.categories = [some tuples]
        self.subcategories = [some tuples]

    def close(self, spider): # Execution ends here
        pass # This is not being executed
        if self.categories:
            for cat in self.categories:
                url = "https://www.doman.org/search/getAjaxResult?categoryId={}".format(cat[0])
                yield Request(url, meta={'tup': cat, 'priority': 0}, priority=0, callback=self.parse_category)
            self.categories = []
            raise DontCloseSpider
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `close` method is a static method: [https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py#L101](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L101) so your `close` method signature don't match.

Comment: How I should define the method? I tried @staticmethod and if I do that it isn't even called.

Comment: I don't think that adding additional urls in the `close` method (since you cannot override it) is good solution. You might want to define callbacks method to parse the categories once you got these in your `parse_main_page` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register this function like this

```
class IndexSpider(Spider):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        super(IndexSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def spider_closed(self, spider): 
        pass # This is not being executed
        if self.categories:
            for cat in self.categories:
                url = "https://www.doman.org/search/getAjaxResult?categoryId={}".format(cat[0])
                yield Request(url, meta={'tup': cat, 'priority': 0}, priority=0, callback=self.parse_category)
            self.categories = []
            raise DontCloseSpider
```

Also I am not sure if you can send requests any more from within `spider_closed` function because Spider has already been closed there.

In your case I suggest you to remove all code from `spider_closed` method and just write any print message like this

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
      logging.info("spider_closed() called")
```

So this way you know `spider_closed` was called, and then try to send Request form within that method.